# HTML/CSS: navigation bar won't fit inside the container layout

Tags: html, css

Why does my navigation bar overflow the container, as in the linked picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGoOd.png

Here's the part that contains navigation in HTML:

```css
    body {
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     background-image: url('../Images/Background1.jpg');
    }


    #wrapper {
     width: 1000px;
     margin: 0px auto;
    }


    #header {
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 10px 0px;
    }
    #logo img {
     float: left;
    }
    #logo1 img {
     margin-top: 30px;
     float: right;
    }


    #banner {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #666666;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     padding: 10px 0px;
    }
    li {
     list-style-type: none;
    }
    #nav {
     background-color: #333333;
     font-size: 13px;
     clear: both;
    }
    #nav ul {
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     background-color: #333333;
     margin: 0px;
    }
    #nav ul li{
     display: inline;
    }
    #nav a:link {
     color: white;
    }
    #nav a:visited {
     color: white;
    }
    #nav a:active {
     color: white;
    }
    #nav a:hover {
     color: white;
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    #nav a:focus {
     color: white;
    }


    #sidebar  {
     width: 300px;
     height: 700px;
     float: left;
     background-color:#CCCCCC;
    }


    #content {
     width: 700px;
     float: right;
     height: 700px;
     background-color: #E5E5E5;
     overflow: auto;
    }


    #footer {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #666666;
     padding: 20px 0px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="nv1.html">1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="nv2.html">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="nv3.html">3</a></li> 
   <li><a href="nv4.html">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="nv5.html">5</a></li>
   <li><a href="nv6.html">6</a></li>
   <li><a href="nv7.html">7</a></li>
   <li><a href="nv8.html">PROMOTIONS</a></li>
   <li><a href="nv9.html">TRANSPORTATION</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>`
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: use jsfiddle to bundle everything in one place. this is meaningless question without full html/css

Comment: Surrounding code, css?

Comment: @LiamSorsby look at the linked picture: the navigation bar doesn't "fit" with the rest of the layout.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with your CSS. That you've not (yet) included to allow us to help you out...

Comment: @Evert I've seen the image, I can see that it doesn't fit. I suppose it could be classed as a question. Just not a very good one.

Comment: Create a very simple HTML page that includes all the necessary CSS *and* shows this problem, then upload all that to e.g. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). That way we can immediately see the effect.

Comment: @LiamSorsby Sure, not very good or clear. Feel free to improve the question (hence my editing of the title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a padding issue - the extra seems to be the default padding-left for the ul element. Just alter your CSS slightly:

```
#nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k6738v3/)

Comment: Thank you, this is the thing I have missed. I apologize for incomplete code and everything, I'm here for the first time, so I don't know how to use everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be with your use of [`floats`](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) (which isn't a good use in this example.)

Instead, you should be looking to use `absolute positioning`, with `left:0;` or `right:0;` instead.

---

I would also advise using `%'s` as units instead of fixed `px` sizing (that way your site will become more responsive),

---

Plus, you have an extra character after the closing of your last div that isn't actually required.

Comment: Hey, thank you for reviewing this for me. I am still to figure out how to use stackoverflow, seems like an adorable community, I've learned a lot from here, I'm just figuring out what to do next. I was having some issues with height and width of content and sidebar part, but it might be because of the use of floats, so I will check absolute positioning and see what happens. The extra character is me trying to figure out how to post here :D It is sort of confusing for first timers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bellalugosi: Try taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as it will help you get to know how we work. Pretty much, give us a good, workable, understandable issue (with preferably a working sample, the likes of jsfiddle (hint. google that)), and we'll do our best to answer it. In terms of **floats** they're something to (slowly) get away from them, and to use only when you need them